# Git push command with a password flag -p 'password'

Tags: git, github

In order not to enter password each time I push to my remote server, please how do I push some changes and pass in the password flag at the same time in a single command.

```
git add . && git commit -m "new update " && git push live main -password "mypassword"
```

Here is the thing, if each time I could commit a change I need to provide a password especially if I am working on a project that requires constant changes and commits, the time taken to type or paste in password is too repetitive and more so if the password is long or complex.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such flag. Use an SSH key

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+cache+credentials

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+passwordless+push

Answer (score 3):

The two most commonly used methods for passwordless authentication are :

- if you access `live` through ssh : set up an ssh key
- if you access `live` through https : use a credentials manager